# Show the amount of orders made by each customer from London

Tags: mysql, sql

Given two tables: customers and orders

_____CUSTOMERS

| customer_id | customer_name | contact_name | .... | city | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alfreds Futterkiste | Maria Ander | .... | Berlin | Germany |
| 4 | Around the Horn | Thomas Hardy | .... | London | UK |

______ORDERS

| order_id | customer_id | employee_id | .... | shipper_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10254 | 14 | 5 | .... | 2 |
| 10355 | 4 | 6 | .... | 1 |

Show the amount of orders made by each customer from London. Hint: Your solution should contain two columns: customer_id and orders

I try

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id = orders.shipper_id 
WHERE city ='London';
```

Comment: Please read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), so you can do the formatting yourself when asking a question.

Comment: There is a HINT in the question("Your solution should contain two columns"), so why to you do `SELECT *` this will give all columns, and not just the ones that you should have.

Comment: There are two other hints in the question 1) Show the amount and 2) by each customer.   you should do something with those hints.    (Besides asking here how to do it...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by joining the customer and order table then selecting customer_id from customer_table, and then with an aggregate count of orders
Example query:

```
SELECT
       c.customer_id,
       count(distinct o.order_id)
FROM customers as c
LEFT JOIN orders as o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE c.city = 'London'
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most of the way there.  You need a couple of things:

- aggregation
- fix the `JOIN` conditions

Does joining a "customer_id" to a "shipper_id" make sense?  Not really -- and especially when both tables have a `customer_id`.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, COUNT(*) as num_orders
FROM customers c INNER JOIN
     orders o 
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id 
WHERE c.city = 'London'
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

I switched the two tables around.  I just think it is more natural to go from customers to orders.

Note that this only returns customers who have at least one order.  I am guessing that to become a "customer" someone has to make an order.